# Linear Algebra - How to use a matrix to check if a vector is in the image of another matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

QUESTION HAS BEEN SOLVED! THANKS FOR EVERYONE THAT HELPED!

I am currently working on some homework for my linear algebra class but I am stuck on one of my questions. I essentially need to figure out how to use one matrix to check if a vector, from that first matrix, is in the image of another matrix. I really don't know where to begin with this process so I appreciate any and all help. Thanks!

Here are the matrices. $$A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 &0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0& 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 1\\ 1 & 1 &0 &0 & 1\\ 1 & 1 &1 & 0 & 0\\ 1 & 0 &1 & 1 & 0\\ 1 & 0& 0 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix},B=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 0 & 0 &1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0& 0& 1 & 0 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0& 0 & 1 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Edit: Here is the full question I am trying to answer: Explain how to use Matrix B to check whether or not a vector is in the image of Matrix A. For example, of the three vectors <1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1>, <1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0>, and <1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1>, exactly one is in the image of Matrix A. Which one and why?

Comment: $\mathbf{b}$ is in the image of $A$ if and only if the system of linear equations $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$ has a solution.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin This going to be a stupid question, but how do I figure out if Ax=b has a solution? Matrix A is a 9x5 matrix, while Matrix B is 4x9. I already have the image of Matrix A and just need to see what specific vector from Matrix B is in there.

Comment: @UptwonDJ The standard method is Gaussian, or Gauss-Jordan elimination, which involves row-reducing an augmented matrix. Have you seen anything like this before?

Comment: @TheoBendit Correct me if I am wrong, but isn't that just bringing a matrix into rref (row reduced echelon form)? If so, would the first step just be getting Martix B into rref?

Comment: @UptwonDJ Maybe consider editing your question to include the matrices in question.

Comment: @Seeker I have updated the post with an Imgur link that has a screenshot of both matrix A and B. I would've updated the post by directly adding the matrices in, but I am not sure how to format that.

Comment: @UptwonDJ Yes, this is the process I mean. No, what you want to do is take whatever column $b$ (from $B$ or elsewhere) that you want to determine is in the image of $A$, augment it to $A$ (to form $[A|b]$), then row-reduce this matrix. If the row-reduced form of this matrix features no zero rows with non-zero scalars in the augmented column, then the system is consistent, and $b$ does lie in the image of $A$. Incidentally, you can also augment the entirety of $B$ to $A$ (to form $[A | B]$) and row-reduce to determine the same thing simultaneously for all columns of $B$.

Comment: @UptwonDJ That's good. [Click here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how to use mathjax to type math on this site. I will try to edit it in for you this time.

Comment: @TheoBendit So I have tried this with three vectors since the question does say that 1 out of a list of 3 vectors will be in the image of Matrix A. These vectors are: <1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1>, <1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0>, and <1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1>. When I augment them to Matrix A and get them all into rref, I get a lot of zeroes but in one specific position, there is the number 1 for every vector that I do. Wouldn't this mean that all three of these vectors are in the image of matrix A?

Comment: @Seeker Thank you for updating the post. I appreciate it!

Comment: @UptwonDJ You're welcome!

Comment: @UptwonDJ That depends on $A$. I haven't worked it out, but you should be row-reducing:$$[A|B^\top]=\left[\begin{array}{ccccc|cccc}1&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1\\0&1&0&0&0&1&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0&0&0&1&1&0\\0&0&0&1&0&0&0&1&1\\0&0&0&0&1&1&0&0&1\\1&1&0&0&1&1&0&0&0\\1&1&1&0&0&0&1&0&0\\1&0&1&1&0&0&0&1&0\\1&0&0&1&1&0&0&0&1\end{array}\right]$$until you get$$[A|B^\top]=\left[\begin{array}{ccccc|cccc}1&0&0&0&0&*&*&*&*\\0&1&0&0&0&*&*&*&*\\0&0&1&0&0&*&*&*&*\\0&0&0&1&0&*&*&*&*\\0&0&0&0&1&*&*&*&*\\0&0&0&0&0&*&*&*&*\\0&0&0&0&0&*&*&*&*\\0&0&0&0&0&*&*&*&*\\0&0&0&0&0&*&*&*&*\end{array}\right].$$

Comment: If any of the $*$s in the zero rows has non-zero entries, then the corresponding columns were not in the range of $A$.

Comment: @TheoBendit So, I have tried again. I don't know if I am doing something wrong but I have consistently gotten 1 in all of the columns of the augmented part in row 4.

Comment: @UptwonDJ There's nothing wrong with that. It would be more telling if you got $1$s (or anything else non-zero) in row $6$, $7$, $8$, or $9$. If you are getting $0$s in those rows, then *all* columns belong in the image of $A$.

Comment: @TheoBendit Sorry, I wrote my response to you incorrectly. I meant to say that I get 1 in row 6 for all columns in the augmented part. I have also updated the post with the full question that I am trying to figure out how to solve.

Comment: Rather than updating the title to indicate thar the question has been answered, consider accepting the given answer if it was indeed helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @TheoBendit I do have another question for you. So I found the vector to be 100110101. Now I need to find a second vector. The formula I am supposed to use is: y=Ax. So y is the vector that I just found (100110101), A is the first matrix, and x is a new vector that I need to find. The hint that I am given is to look at the first 5 rows of Matrix A. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: I'm voting to close as the proceedings seemed to have stopped short of proving useful content for future Readers facing similar problems, switching instead to using the above Comment to ask about a different problem.  Instead that should be posted separately with a link to this one for helpful context.

Answer (score 0):

If a vector $v$ is in the image of $A,$ then there is a linear combination of the columns of $A$ that equals $v$

There is only one column of A corresponding to each of the first 5 components of a vector in the image of A.

If the first row of $B$ is in the image of $A$ then:

$\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\\0\\1\\1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 0\\1\\0\\0\\0\\1\\1\\0\\0 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\0\\1\\1\\0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\\0\\1\\1\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$

That is the only combination of vector in $A$ that will have the proper components for the first 5 components of that vector in $B.$  But we see that the rest of the components don't match.  So that vector is not in the image of $A$

Comment: When I add up all those first 3 vectors as you have shown, I don't get any of the vectors that I are supposed to be in the image of the Matrix A. Is there another way to solve this problem or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: each of those vectors and any combination thereof is in the image of A.  I don't see that the row vectors in B are in the image of A

Comment: If this answer works, mark it with the green check. You do not need to edit your title as "SOLVED" as the green check will indicate that.

Comment: @SeanRoberson It didn't work for me. A earlier comment helped me a little bit.